# Angular 2 - how to add a custom class?

Tags: angular

I try to add a regular class to my project but I get

```
zone.js:917 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'Tools' declared by the module 'AppModule'. 
Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
```

it's just a regular typescript class that I want to be able to use verywhere in my project

it is not a directive, nor pipe, nor a component

```
export class Tools
{
    pascalCase(text:string)
    {
        return text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
    }
}
```

here is the app module

```
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/core';

...    

import { Tools } from './tools.class';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        routing,
        CustomErrorHandlerModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ...
        Tools
    ],
```

thanks

Comment: There is nothing to do. Don't add it to `declarations`. Just add a TypeScript import to make it known to the code file where you want to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Tools` from `declarations`. There is no reason to add it if it's not a component, directive, or pipe.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add Tools into App Module,

`declarations:` is used to declare components, directives, pipes that belongs to the current module. Everything inside declarations knows each other.

so just remove `Tools` from declaration.